# Using a Flood Fill Algorith to create an Array

Tags: java, recursion, flood-fill

I'm using a flood fill algorithm to sort through an image. If it encounters the same color, I want it copy that pixel over into an identically sized array called filled. The array filled is then transformed back into an image and saved as a jpg. However, when I open the jpg, it appears entirely black.

```
public static void findFace(int[][] image) throws IOException {
    int height = image.length;
    int width = image[0].length;

    Color centerStart = new Color(image[width / 2][height / 2]);
    int[][] filled = new int[width][height];

    floodFill(width / 2, height / 2, centerStart, image, filled);

    //construct the filled array as image. Show if the face was found.
    BufferedImage bufferImage2 = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            int Pixel = filled[x][y] << 16 | filled[x][y] << 8 | filled[x][y];
            bufferImage2.setRGB(x, y, Pixel);
        }
    }

    //save filled array as image file
    File outputfile = new File("/home/lily/Pictures/APicaDay/saved.jpg");
    ImageIO.write(bufferImage2, "jpg", outputfile);
}

public static int[][] floodFill(int x, int y, Color targetColor, int[][] image, int[][] filled) {
    if (image[x][y] != targetColor.getRGB()) {
        return filled;
    }

    filled[x][y] = image[x][y];

    floodFill(x - 1, y, targetColor, image, filled);
    floodFill(x + 1, y, targetColor, image, filled);
    floodFill(x, y - 1, targetColor, image, filled);
    floodFill(x, y + 1, targetColor, image, filled);

    return filled;
}
```

bonus question: I would like the flood fill to also accept colors that are similar, but not the exact same, since I'm dealing with a photograph.

Comment: The bit shifting to create `Pixel` seems a little odd... It seems like you haven't made up your mind if you have 3 byte RGB or int RGB samples.  It's also hard to know what `int[][] image` really is. Try posting a fully runnable, but stripped down version of your code.

Comment: Also, are you not covering the same pixel multiple times? The recursion seems a little out of control. You also need bounds checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `floodFill` function you've posted is missing two important elements:

1. If the area containing the same color as the first pixel extends all the way to the boundary of the image, the function will try to access `image` at an invalid index. You can fix this by first checking the x and y coordinates of the pixel you are checking, and returning immediately if they are out of bounds.
2. If there is more than one adjacent pixel of the same color, the function will cause recurse infinitely, since the initial call will call `floodFill` on the second pixel, which will then proceed to call `floodFill` on the first pixel, and so on. You need a way to make sure that you only call `floodFill` on a particular pixel once.

Since you're not observing either of these two symptoms, and you don't observe anything from the resulting image, I guess that the initial pixel's color check is not correct. When you pass an integer to the `Color` constructor, are you sure that it uses an RBG interpretation of that integer?

Comment: I made suggested adjustments to the recursion, which still results in a black jpg. I'll do more research into how to use the Color constructor properly. You're right, that's probably the root of the issue. Thank you for the help.